# Upload file to bitbucket repo

Tags: bitbucket-api

I am unable to find the exact REST API end points to upload a zip file to Bitbucket repository using REST API. Please help. https://docs.atlassian.com/bitbucket-server/rest/7.12.1/bitbucket-build-rest.html

I am following the above documents.